# Slow vlookup and countifs

Tags: vba, performance, excel, processing-efficiency

I am trying to fill a table with the count of how many registers I have, having the same day, week and hour, and that count divided in the number of years in which I can find the same week.

I've done this code in VBA but it's really slow, so if you can help me to improve this solution, I will really appreciate it.

```
    Sub formulacion()
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim years As Integer
    Dim rango_semana As Range
    Dim rango_dia As Range
    Dim rango_hora As Range
    Dim rango_sede As Range
    Dim rango_busqueda As Range



    a = 2
    For a = 2 To 319
        If Sheets("Dinamicos").Cells(5, a) <> "" Then
        b = 6
            For b = 6 To 20

            semana = Sheets("Dinamicos").Cells(3, a)
            dia = Sheets("Dinamicos").Cells(5, a)
            hora = Sheets("Dinamicos").Cells(b, 1)
            sede = Sheets("Dinamicos").Cells(4, 1)
            LastRow = Sheets("Base").Cells(Sheets("Base").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Set rango_semana = Sheets("Base").Range("AK2:AK" & LastRow)
            Set rango_dia = Sheets("Base").Range("AG2:AG" & LastRow)
            Set rango_hora = Sheets("Base").Range("AJ2:AJ" & LastRow)
            Set rango_sede = Sheets("Base").Range("J2:J" & LastRow)
            Set rango_busqueda = Sheets("Base").Range("AK2:AN" & LastRow)

            lookupvalue = Application.VLookup(semana, rango_busqueda, 4, False)
               If IsError(lookupvalue) Then
               years = 1
              'Si lo encuentra lo devuelve
               Else
               years = lookupvalue
               End If

            Sheets("Dinamicos").Cells(b, a) = (WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rango_semana, semana, rango_dia, dia, rango_hora, hora, rango_sede, sede)) / years

            Next b
        End If
        b = 6
  Next a


  End Sub
```

Comment: If the code works and all you need is help improving the code, then this is too broad for this site and should be on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: 1. You could start by setting all of the ranges outside your For .. Next loop. It does not appear to be necessary to continually set and reset them for every iteration of the loop. 2. `application.match` is faster than vlookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the var assignments change within the nested For ... Next loop iterations; others do not. Don't keep reassigning vars that do not change.

`Application.Match` is faster than `Application.Vlookup`.

You do not have to set and reset the values in `a` and `b` before using them in the loop and nested loop. They are assigned their start value upon entering the loop(s).

```
lastRow = Worksheets("Base").Cells(Worksheets("Base").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rango_semana = Worksheets("Base").Range("AK2:AK" & lastRow)
Set rango_dia = Worksheets("Base").Range("AG2:AG" & lastRow)
Set rango_hora = Worksheets("Base").Range("AJ2:AJ" & lastRow)
Set rango_sede = Worksheets("Base").Range("J2:J" & lastRow)
Set rango_busqueda = Worksheets("Base").Range("AK2:AN" & lastRow)
sede = Worksheets("Dinamicos").Cells(4, 1)

For a = 2 To 319
    If Worksheets("Dinamicos").Cells(5, a) <> "" Then
        semana = Worksheets("Dinamicos").Cells(3, a)
        dia = Worksheets("Dinamicos").Cells(5, a)

        For b = 6 To 20

            hora = Sheets("Dinamicos").Cells(b, 1)

            lookupvalue = Application.Match(semana, rango_busqueda.Columns(1), False)
            If IsError(lookupvalue) Then
               years = 1
              'Si lo encuentra lo devuelve
            Else
               years = rango_busqueda.Cells(lookupvalue, 4).Value2
            End If

            Worksheets("Dinamicos").Cells(b, a) = (WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rango_semana, semana, rango_dia, dia, rango_hora, hora, rango_sede, sede)) / years

        Next b
    End If
Next a
```

Finally, remember that Sheets is not the same as Worksheets.